# Override Only 1 <Line Number> Action Per Import Scenario

Tags: web, import, acumatica

There is only one -1  Action Per Import Scenario.

[image]

Adding any new ones will get automatically cleaned up by the import scenario.

This is a severe limitation for automation purposes and **if the BLC can be customized to override this limitation... I think the import scenario's instructions should still run just fine... Any idea how to customize it?**

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Import a single Journal Transaction with multiple lines?

Comment: @Gabriel yes exactly

Comment: You will have to create one line per account in your Excel file. System will insert it to the same GL batch number.

Comment: @Gabriel But then this will also require the batch # to be in the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Gabriel mentioned in the comments to import Master-Detail records you must have one line per detail with each line repeating the master record's information.
You cannot with only one line import more that one entry and a detail is considered an entry.

Thought if you really want to do it with only one call you might want to take a look at the contract based API. With it, it is possible to upload a complete Master details record, thought it will be only one at the time.

Comment: Yes, this is the truth so far but my question originally is aimed towards overriding the limitation of only one <Line Number> per scenario (possibly via customization)